# When using Deeplab, with a custom dataset, should you add descriptors to more than just the segmentation_dataset.py file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently using DeepLab for a segmentation project and i am wondering why most tutorials only mention updating a single script that goes by the name of *segmentation_dataset.py* with a descriptor of the split with regards to your own dataset,

```
_BLABLABLA = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 5,
        'val': 3,
        'trainval': 8,
    },
    num_classes=3,  # 2 foreground + 1 background
    ignore_label=255,
)
```

plus a name for that dataset under,

```
_DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
    'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
    'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
    'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
    'bla': _BLABLABLA,
}
```

This is all fine but if you dig deeper into the code, you (or I) will realize that in the train.py script, a .py file that goes by the name of *data_generator.py* is called. When opened, it contains a list of characteristics for each dataset. Now the funny part is, no tutorial on DeepLab mentions that you should update this .py script (data_generator) with the description of your dataset just like in *segmentation_dataset.py*.

How can this be? The dataset name, which is a flag and consequently a *train.py* parameter, is by default pointing to the pascal dataset. So if you were to use your own dataset how are you telling train.py "I want you to pay attention to the characteristics of *bla*" rather than pascal?

P.S Some would say that you don't need to worry about it because all your data is captured in your tfrecords. But still, not explicitly naming your dataset has to have some consequence right?